# Do bans on AWS SES accounts extend to sibling accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I have a root account with 3 subaccounts on AWS. I am using AWS SES (Simple Email Service) on all 3 subaccounts.

```
If my subaccount gets banned from SES, will this ban extend to all my other sibling/parent accounts?
```

Context: I am setting up a new service which will use SES extensively and I would like to isolate this service in a separate child account (4th one), so that in the eventuality that I get banned, the ban hopefully doesn't extend to the existing 3 child accounts that are already using SES. [The FAQ doesn't cover this](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/).

Comment: What are you doing that you're planning on being banned before you even start? I've never had an account banned so I don't know, and it's not covered in any of the training. If you're doing something actively bad like high volume spamming you'll likely have your all your accounts terminated.

Comment: I'm developing an email-sending service which is going to be heavily used in my organization. On top of this, I have other workflows in my accounts relying on SNS, and a ban on my account would impact all other workflows as well.

I've read horror stories on forums regarding bans on SNS out of nowhere and draconic measures which disable your account for weeks, which would be unacceptable in my case. That's why I'm looking contingency measures. By no means am I planning on spamming.

Comment: Hopefully someone can help. Two things I would consider 1) Reach out to AWS to get an AWS account manager, who will be able to help a lot 2) Use a different email delivery service / hosting system if you're really worried. I've been using AWS commercially for years and never had / heard of anyone banned, but we haven't done anything with high volume email.